# Sockets with QT

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

How do I send data over sockets in C++ in QT ?
Here's my attempt, it does not work, regards

the server side that sends a file

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString url("127.0.0.1");
    sock.bind(QHostAddress(url), 1440);
    sock.connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 1440);
    sock.write("Coucou");
    sock.close();
}
```

and the client that receives the file

```
void MainWindowClient::checker() {
    csock.connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 1440);
    char *datas;
    sock.read(datas, 10000000);
    ui->label->setText(datas);
    csock.close();
}
```

When i run the program, it does not display "Coucou" as the label set on the client, why ?

Comment: That code is undefined; you need to allocate space for the data you read. This is not specific to networking. You might want to read a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

Are you forced to use Sockets or can you use Websockets too? If so, Qt has a wonderful way to deal with Websockets and Signals / Slots.

For example, here's what I use for my [Remote Control App](https://github.com/MBach/Miam-Player-qt-remote) on my smartphone to control my [Music Player](https://github.com/MBach/Miam-Player) (the code has been truncated). But the server can also send commands to synchronize the UI on the smartphone.

### The client:

```
RemoteClient::RemoteClient(CoverProvider *coverProvider, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , _socket(new QWebSocket("remote", QWebSocketProtocol::VersionLatest, this))
{
    connect(_socket, &QWebSocket::textMessageReceived, this, &RemoteClient::processTextMessage);
}

/// Direction: Remote App is receiving orders from Server
void RemoteClient::processTextMessage(const QString &message)
{
    if (message.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    QStringList list = message.split(QChar::Null);
    if (list.size() <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    int command = list.first().toInt();
    switch (command) {
    case CMD_Playback:
        // Nothing
        break;
    case CMD_State: {
        QMediaPlayer::State state = (QMediaPlayer::State) list.at(1).toInt();
        if (state == QMediaPlayer::PlayingState) {
            emit playing();
        } else if (state == QMediaPlayer::PausedState) {
            emit paused();
        } else {
            emit stopped();
        }
        break;
    }
    case CMD_Track: 
        /// etc.
        break;
    }
    /// etc.
    default:
        break;
    }
}

/// Direction: Remote App is sending orders to Server
void RemoteClient::setVolume(qreal v)
{
    QStringList args = { QString::number(CMD_Volume), QString::number(v) };
    _socket->sendTextMessage(args.join(QChar::Null));
}
```

### The server:

```
void RemoteControl::startServer()
{
    auto b = _webSocketServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, _port);
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << b;
}

void RemoteControl::initializeConnection()
{
    /// ...
    connect(mediaPlayer(), &MediaPlayer::volumeChanged, this, &RemoteControl::sendVolume);
}

/// Direction: Server to updating Remote App
void RemoteControl::sendVolume(qreal volume)
{
    QStringList args = { QString::number(CMD_Volume), QString::number(volume) };
    _webSocket->sendTextMessage(args.join(QChar::Null));
}

/// Direction: Remote App is sending command to Server
void RemoteControl::decodeResponseFromClient(const QString &message)
{
    if (message.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    QStringList args = message.split(QChar::Null);
    if (args.count() < 2) {
        return;
    }

    int command = args.first().toInt();

    switch (command) {
    case CMD_Volume: {
        qreal volume = args.at(1).toFloat();
        _currentView->mediaPlayerControl()->mediaPlayer()->setVolume(volume);
        break;
    }
    /// etc.
    }
}
```